# Class A not visible in class C but visible in main. Why?

Tags: c++

```
class A {};

class B : private A {

};

class C : public B {
public:
    void f() {
        A a; // This line causes error, but works when it is in main() function
    }

};

int main()
{
    C c;
    // A a; --> This line works
    return 0;
}
```

I am guessing this has something to do with `B` inheriting privately from `A` but cannot put my finger on it.

EDIT: Error is "class A is not visible". Compiled with g++.

Comment: @KarthikT, I looked. It's the same error as trying to access a private member of a class, though it complains about `A A::A`.

Comment: @KarthikT , Class A not visible

Comment: ok the actual error message is: *error: 'class A' is inaccessible*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

name lookup is separate from access checking. and when you inherit from a class, that class' name is injected into the inheriting class' scope. so in class `C` you pick up the name `A` but it's not accessible.

---

one solution is to write `::A a;` instead of `A a;`.

Comment: Why does the code work outside class C then? Could you please explain more?

Comment: I'm surprised it "blocks" `A` like that.  I understand not being able to access the members (if they existed) of a privately inherited class (that's the intention of private inheritance) but just as declaring a variable in a function... seems odd.

Comment: @Anon: outside class C the compiler doesn't look in the class C scope to find the name A. So it doesn't find B::A.

Answer (score 3):

While Alf's answer is correct, I feel that it could be made a bit clearer (or maybe more confusing, who knows). The name of a class is injected into the scope of the class itself. As he mentions access specifiers are only checked *after* lookup finds what the identifier means. In the code in questions:

```
class A {};
class B : private A {};
struct C : public B {
    void f() {
        A a; // This line causes error, but works when it is in main() function
    }
};
```

When processing `C::f` the compiler sees the identifier `A` and tries to resolve it. It searches in the scope of `C` and it is not present, it moves up the hierarchy and does not find it in `B`, but it finds it inside the base type `A` (lookup resolves the unqualified `A` to be `::A::A`). In this context the identifier `A` is resolved to *the injected name A  inside the base class A of my base class B* and access specifiers are checked. The compiler checks whether it can access *my base class B*, and then whether it can access *it's base class A* but this one is inaccessible due to the `private` inheritance and complains that you cannot access the nested name `A` inside `A`.

By providing the extra qualification `::A` you are directing lookup. In this case, it will find the type `A` in the global namespace, which is perfectly accessible and it will compile.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to explain more thoroughly. now should i go to sleep or fetch my visa card in order to order vinge's "children of the sky"? hm.